# Cygwin placement for RTLD_NEXT?

Tags: c, opengl, replace, cygwin, hook

Is there was any known workaround or other code replacement to implement the following in cygwin, as RTLD_NEXT is NOT defined?

```
int * ptr = dlsym(dlopen(libName,RTLD_NEXT), functionName);
ptr = somefuncaddres;
```

My hope is that I will be able to "hook" onto the glFlush() calls, adding an overlay, similar to that in the program steam.

Comment: Why do you need to mock with glFlush()? Why not coding my_glFlush() and do whatever you want there?

Comment: I wan't to hook onto any program I spawn with spawnl and the like, without the other program having to specify to use a non-gl function.